# Irreducible group representation(algebraic and topological irreducibility)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, unitary-representations

In page 280 of  "C^* algebra" by  Dixmier, in the context of group representation, it is written 'We never encounter the concept of algebraic irreducibility except in finite dimensional Hilbert space".

According to the fact that "For  $C^*$ algebra representation both topological and algebraic irreducibility are the same" so why it is not the case for group representation? What does it mean "We never encounter  algebraic irreducible representation"?
From the view of irreducibility, what is the difference between algebra representation and group representation?

Comment: Algebraic irreducibility for the group is the same as algebraic irreduciblility for the complex group algebra which is much smaller than the C*-algebra if you ignore all topology.  So it shouldn't be that surprising if there are algebraically irreducible reps if the C*-algebra which are not algebraically irreducible for the group.

Comment: The comments to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384903/algebraic-vs-continuous-representations-of-topological-groups give an example

Comment: There is no algebraically irreducible representation of any countable group $G$ on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space!  Any vector $\xi$ lies in the (countably generated, hence) proper subspace  $\text{span}\ G\xi$.  On the other hand, there are surely many examples of topologically irreducible representations!

Comment: @Ruy  if  $G\zeta$ is a finite set for every $\zeta$ is it obvious that $G$ is  necessarilly a finite group?

Comment: @Ali, I didn't quite understand your question.  Could you please expand it.  Do you mean $G\zeta$ finite for all $\zeta$ and **all** representations?

Comment: @Ruy No I do not mean all representation. I mean the representation is fixed  but for every $\zeta \in H$, the span of $G\zeta$ isa  finite dim. s[ace. So in this case I think that  maybe the argument in your first comment does not work.

Comment: If the dimension of the space of the representation is infinite then $\text{span}\ G\zeta$ is always a proper invariant subspace: it is either finite dimensional, or a non-closed infinite dimensional subspace.

Comment: @Ruy: I think it's true that if a Banach space $X$ admits an algebraically cyclic continuous action of a second countable locally compact group, then it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: @Narutaka, thanks.  This is a nice result.  As I indicated above, I can only prove it for countable groups.